# Spring expression language: Using a variable as key for a map lookup in SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to use variable as key to look up a value in a map. I would like to be able to reference the variable directly (in this case `jobTitle`), but for some reason I need to prefix the variable with either `#root.` or `#this.` in order to get it to work. So this works:

```java
parser.parseExpression("{ \"Manager\":\"37.5\", \"CEO\":\"40\"}[#root.jobTitle]"
```

(resolves to "37.5")

but this doesn't

```java
parser.parseExpression("{ \"Manager\":\"37.5\", \"CEO\":\"40\"}[jobTitle]"
```

(resolves to null)

`jobTitle` is a root attribute on the context object. From looking at the SpEL docs it seems like I should be able to reference the attribute directly? Am I doing something wrong?

Full working code below

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Employee employee = new Employee("Joe Bloggs", "Manager");
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(
            "{ \"Manager\":\"37.5\", \"Ceo\":\"40\"}[#root.jobTitle]");
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(employee);
    context.setRootObject(employee);
    System.out.println(exp.getValue(context, String.class));
}

static class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String jobTitle;

    Employee(String firstName, String jobTitle) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From looking at the SpEL docs it seems like I should be able to reference the attribute directly?

This is correct for below case, both will print "Manager"

```java
System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("#root.jobTitle").getValue(context, String.class));
System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("jobTitle").getValue(context, String.class));
```

But for expression inside `[]`, the handling is different. Since there is no language specification for SpEL, I can just explain base on the behaviour.
When you run

```java
System.out.println(parser.parseExpression(
           "{\"jobTitle\":\"37.5\"}[jobTitle]").getValue(context, String.class));
```

This will actually print "37.5"(`[jobTitle]` is treated as `[\"jobTitle\"]`). The author decided to make it easier to access value of Map, and the drawback is you need to specify with `#root.jobTitle` when referencing the root object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're absolutely right - I'd assumed that if the value in the square brackets wasn't enclosed in quotes, it would be resolved as a variable rather than a string literal value.
For me, this behaviour isn't quite consistent (but I'm not one of the authors and I'm mighty thankful to them for creating the library).


Do you know if there is a way to change this behaviour using some some sort of  hook into SpEL?


I'm tempted to pre-process any expressions and look for values between square brackets and pre-pend them with `#root.` if it's not a string literal.

Comment: Just to be clear on my use-case: business users will be writing these expressions and I want the syntax to be as 'natural' as possible - i.e. they shouldn't need to know or care that it's SpEL, which is why not having the `#root.` prefix would be preferable.

Comment: I don't find any simple solution to change this behaviour. Maybe consider use `get()` instead of `[]`, like `"{ \"Manager\":\"37.5\", \"Ceo\":\"40\", \"jobTitle\": 2}.get(jobTitle)"`. Of course pre-processing the expression to add `#root` can be a solution, but it is error-prone, especially when the expression is complex.

Comment: I think the `.get(jobTitle)` might be a good compromise. Thanks for your help